# How to update jar file inside ear file

Tags: java, jar, ear

To update a jar file adding one class I can use it:
jar -uvf

But I need to update a jar file inside a ear file, I tried the command below but it did not work:
jar -uvf NameOfEarfile.ear:FolderName/NameOfJar.jar path/NameOfClass.class

Could someone help me on it?

Comment: It'd be best repackage the EAR again.

Comment: I need to do this in one unix server and I would like to add just one class when I am testing some fix.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do is using 7zip software.

Comment: I need to do this in one unix server and I would like to add just one class when I am testing some fix.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to update the ear/war/zip/jar file. Before the execute of below code first convert the file into unix format.

Copy the below code in TestUpdate.sh file and copy to unix server. Then use below commands. Make sure the TestUpdate.sh, class files (which you want to copy inside the EAR/WAR/ZIP/jar) and the EAR/WAR/ZIP/jar file all are in same directory.

```
dos2unix TestUpdate.sh
. ./TestUpdate.sh FileNameWhichYouWantToUpdate # EAR/WAR/JAR/ZIP filename
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#LearName='TEST.ear'
LearName=$1
jar xf $LearName
for clas in *.class
do                    
  echo "Checking for $clas ..."
  for f in *.jar
    do
      result=$(jar tf $f | grep -w $clas)
      if [ -n "$result" ]; then
        echo "$f contains $result"

        Lp="${#clas}";
        Lr="${#result}";
        count=$((Lr-Lp));
        #echo $count
        dirC=${result:0:$count};
        echo "Directory $dirC"
        echo $dirC
        mkdir -p $dirC;
        echo "Copying $clas $dirC"
        cp $clas $dirC;
        echo "updating $f ..."
        jar ufv $f $result;
        file_write "updating $f ..."
        echo "Updating $LearName ..."

        jar ufv $LearName $f;
        echo "-----------------------------------------------"

        break
      fi                                             
    done
done    
rm -f *.jar ---- comment this line if your input file is .jar. If your input file is EAR/WAR/ZIP file then NO need to comment this line
rm -r *.war
rm -r META-INF
rm -f *.tmp
rm -r com
```